# Show that there exists a unique weak solution to $L(u): =- \text{div}(p\nabla u) + qu = f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm going through a set of problems on partial differential equations and one of the problems absolutely stumped me. It goes as follows:

Given $Q$ a bounded and open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $p \in C^1(\bar Q)$, $\min_{Q} p(x) \geq p_0 > 0$, $q \in C(\bar Q)$, $q \geq 0$, $f \in L^2(Q)$, show that there exists a unique solution in $H^1(Q)$ to

\begin{cases} 
L(u) &= - \text{div}(p\nabla u) + qu = f(x), & &x \in Q \\ 
u &= 0, & &x \in \partial Q 
\end{cases}

Now I've tried the obvious thing, to apply the Lax-Milgram theorem for

$$B[u,v] = \int_{Q} p(x)\langle\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle-v\langle\nabla p,\nabla u\rangle + quv \; dx ,$$

but I've been unable to find a suitable bottom bound of $B[u,u]$.

Without that bound, I can show that there exists a $\mu \geq 0$ such that

$$\begin{cases} 
L(u) + \mu u &= f(x), & &x \in Q \\ 
u &= 0, & &x \in \partial Q 
\end{cases}$$

has a unique solution in $H^1(Q)$, which implies that the original problem has a solution, but that gets me no closer to establishing its uniqueness.

Apparently, the way to go is to construct a functional $E(v)$, which is minimized only at the solution. For an example of this method, if we set

$$F(v) = \int_{Q}|\nabla v|^2 \;dx - 2\int_{Q}fv\; dx$$

then $F$ is uniquely minimised at $u$, where $u$ is a weak solution to

\begin{cases} 
-\Delta u &= f(x), & &x \in Q \\ 
u &= 0, & &x \in \partial Q 
\end{cases}

In fact $F(v)-F(u)\geq \int_{Q}|\nabla(v) - \nabla(u)|^2 \;dx$, so $F$ is minimized at exactly one point.

Could anyone show me how does one go about constructing such a functional? I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: To construct a functional for your original problem for arbitrary $v$, multiply by $v$ and integrate by parts, using the boundary condition to make the evaluated term vanish, to get $$E(v) := \int_{Q} p \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + q u v - f v dx = 0$$ Just so you know, construction of a function is quite often 'multiply the PDE by $v$ (or $\nabla v$, or $\nabla^{2} v$ etc.), integrate by parts, use the boundary condition to eliminate the evaluated terms and choose $v$ appropriately.

Comment: @mattos 
I can see how using this approach we can define $$E(v) = \int_{Q}p|\nabla v|^2+qv^2-fv \; dx$$
and that this gives $E(u) = 0$ for any solution $u$. But why would $0$ be the minimum?

Comment: Sorry, your last question doesn't make sense to me. Could you clarify what you mean by 'why would $0$ be the minimum'? The minimum of what?

Comment: @mattos The minimum value of E.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you are referring to the fact that $E = 0$, which follows by construction, or the fact that $u$ minimises $E$. The quantity $E$ is minimised by taking the [first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) and demanding that this quantity vanishes, much like you compute the first derivative of a function and set it equal to zero to find the critical points. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) for more.